# Error working with "ScrollElasticSearchHttp" processor in NiFi

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-nifi

I am trying to retrieve data from an index in ElasticSearch. I configured the "QueryElasticSearchHttp" processor and it works just fine. However when  I try to use the ScrollElasticsearchHttp processor with the same URL, query, index properties and set the 'scroll' to default 1 minute, it doesn't work.

I get an error response of 404 : "Elasticsearch returned code 404 with message Not found". 
I am also tailing the log on the ES cluster and I see this error;

```
[DEBUG][o.e.a.s.TransportSearchScrollAction] [2] Failed to execute query phase
org.elasticsearch.transport.RemoteTransportException:[127.0.0.1:9300][indices:data/read/search[phase/query+fetch/scroll]]
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.search.SearchContextMissingException: No search context found for id [2]
at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.getExecutor(SearchService.java:457) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.2.jar:7.5.2]
```

I am on Apache NiFi 1.10.0

Here is the config for the processor: 
I should see a total of 441 hits, and with page size 20 I should see 23 queries being made to ES. 
But I don't get a single result back. I have tried higher values for "scroll" and also played around with "page size" to no avail.

I also noticed that even though the ScrollElasticsearchHttp processor is set to run every 1m, on the ES log I don't see any error log repeated every minute.

[image]

[image]

**Update:**

When I cleared the state via UI: "View state" -> "Clear State", I was able to make a single call, that returned a page full of hits in one flowfile. 
However, there are more pages to be retrieved. How do I make the processor to go fetch the next page?

My understanding was that the single invocation of the ScrollElasticsearchHttp will page through all the result sets and bring in each page as one flowfile. Is this not correct?

Answer (score 0):

Please decrease the scheduling time to around 10-20 sec. So in every 10-20 sec processor will fetch the next set of records based on your page size.
You can check the state value when the fetching process is in progress i.e. you will find a scroll id in it. Once the fetching process is complete then state value will be changed to "finishedQuery" : true.